# Why, when I try to read Elf32_Shdr, does the fread () function throw a segmentation error?

Tags: c

Code:

```
bool elf32_get_section_header(FILE * file, const Elf32_Ehdr * elf_header, unsigned int index, Elf32_Shdr * header) {                                                                                                     
unsigned int offset = elf_header->e_shoff + elf_header->e_shentsize * index;   
 if (fseek(file, offset, SEEK_SET))
      return false;

    return (fread(header, sizeof(Elf32_Shdr), 1, file) == 1);
}

  bool elf32_get_section_header_by_name(FILE * file, const Elf32_Ehdr * elf_header, const char * name, Elf32_Shdr * header) {
    bool ret = false;                                                                                        

    for (int i = 0; (i < elf_header->e_shnum) && (!ret); ++i) {
        printf("\n%d\n", i);
        if (!elf32_get_section_header(file, elf_header, i, header))
            return false;

        char * section_name = elf32_get_string(file, elf_header, header->sh_name);                              
        ret = (strcmp(name, section_name) == 0);
        free(section_name);
    }
    return ret;
}

int main() {

 uintptr_t addd = scan_maps();

 FILE* file = fopen("libprog.so", "rb");
 if(!file)
 {
  puts("\nError fopen!\n");
  return 1;
 }

 Elf32_Ehdr* elf_head;
 if(!get_elf32_header(elf_head, file))
 {
   puts("\nError get header!\n");
   return 1;
 }

 Elf32_Shdr* sec_head;
 if(!elf32_get_section_header_by_name(file, elf_head, ".got", sec_head))
 {
   puts("\nError geting section header by name\n");
 }
```

Error in elf32_get_section_header. More precisely here: return (fread (header, sizeof (Elf32_Shdr), 1, file) == 1);

P.s I really need help, I no longer understand how to approach this task correctly

Comment: seigneur, there is no function pointer in the code. What did you mean?

Comment: Here is the initialization:
Elf32_Shdr * sec_head;
 if (! elf32_get_section_header_by_name (file, elf_head, ".got", sec_head))
{}

Comment: I understand what a pointer is. I declared a pointer of type Elf32_Shdr and passed it to this function for initialization. You do not seem to understand the purpose of this function. fseek () moves the cursor to the specified offset in Elf32_shdr, and then fread () reads the structure from this point and fills our Elf32_Shdr * sec_heed

Comment: Isn't the fact that this pointer points to the Elf32_Shdr structure considered initialization?

Comment: fread () here plays the role of a placeholder structure. According to the idea, fread () takes a buffer to fill, in this situation, the structure plays the role of a buffer, this is the Elf32_Shdr structure. This method usually works. I took this function from Samsung:
https://github.com/Samsung/ADBI/blob/master/procutil/elf.c
I took this function because I understand how it works. Most likely, we did not understand each other

Comment: I think I will find a solution. Thanks so much for deciding to help me

Answer (score 0):

Two variables must be declared, not two pointers:

```
Elf32_Ehdr elf_head;
Elf32_Shdr sec_head;
```

And pass their addresses to functions:

`get_elf32_header (& elf_head, file);`

AND

`elf32_get_section_header_by_name (file, & elf_head, ".plt", & sec_head)`